# appending data to a dictionary froma CSV file in a loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

i am reading data from a csv file where i have for example in the columns
a name, gender, age...

i want to store this data in a dictionary but the update value clears the previous entries and you can not append to a dictionary...

i have seen that the way to do this would be like this:

```
Profiles = {}

for rows in data:

    Profile = {'name':rows[0],'gender':rows[1],'age':rows[2]}

    Profiles[entry1] = Profile 
print(Profiles)

file.close()
```

how can i loop through this and just have each entry as 1, 2, 3, etc...how do i loop through through?

Comment: If `entry1` is different for every iteration of loop, `Profiles` will not clear the previously added values. Check if `entry1` is different  for every iteration.

Comment: entry1 is not defined though? how do i define it lol

Comment: @Elusive_DODO You can see my answer how I assigned values to `entry`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you did not change entry value in a loop.
By using `enumerate()`, you can get entry values, such as 0, 1, 2 .... Then, you can use it to keep `Profiles` updated, as follows:

```py
Profiles = {}
for entry, rows in enumerate(data):
    Profile = {'name': rows[0], 'gender': rows[1], 'age': rows[2]}
    Profiles[entry] = Profile  # so that entry value can be 0, 1, 2 ...  every turn in a loop

print(Profiles)
```

If you start the entry value from 1 instead of 0, then use `list(enumerate(data, 1))` instead of `enumerate(data)`.